# Copy User field values to Case field

Tags: case, user

I have created a new custom `Formula Field` called `Locale` on the `Case` object. I want to extract all values which are available on `User` object (`Locale` field values) to this `Case Locale` field. How? without using Apex Class we can use validation Rule or formula Field or any other Method

Comment: I don't think the question is properly framed to get a satisfactory answer, but they do look the same. @Salesforce are you trying to copy the locale value from a specific `User` record via formula? Are you trying to create an identical picklist?

Comment: I want to create an identical Picklist in User LocalesidKey(all Values) to case object Custom Field (Locale) which i have been Created ,any Method but Not Apex Class